# função se - verdadeiro copia celula e cola noutra

Tags: funções, microsoft-excel

Necessito de uma pequena ajuda. 
Tenho uma folha de excel e quero fazer o seguinte: 
Nesta função

```
= SE(F10=O11;Copia valor celula G2 e cola na celula G10;"falso")
```

Quero fazer uma comparação e caso seja verdadeiro copia o valor da celula G2 e cola na celula G10.

Comment: Se você digitar a fórmula na célula **G10** é fácil: `=SE(F10=O11;G10;"falso")`

Answer (score 2):

Realmente o método passado pelo Ricardo Pontual no comentário é mais fácil.

Mas se realmente precisar de um VBA, use

```
Sub se_condicao()

If Range("F10").Value = Range("O11").Value Then
   Range("G2").Copy Range("G10")
End If

End Sub
```